# Detect programming language of a snippet using Pygments

Tags: python, oop, lexer, pygments

I'm using the [`guess_lexer()`](http://pygments.org/docs/api/#pygments.lexers.guess_lexer) method of Pygments library to identify the source code in a snippet:

This is how I'm using it right now:

```
from pygments.lexers import guess_lexer
text = "string containing source code"
lexer_subclass = guess_lexer(text)
print str(lexer_subclass)
```

And based on the language present in the `text` variable, it will return something like:

```
<pygments.lexers.PythonLexer>
```

What I want is only the `PythonLexer` part. I'm aware that I can get it using string manipulation, but it feels hacky. I want to do it in the *correct* way.

So I tried to see what Pygment's doing internally and found [this method](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/pygments-main/src/7941677dc77d4f2bf0bbd6140ade85a9454b8b80/pygments/lexer.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#lexer.py-112) which is responsible for outputting the lexer name:

```
def __repr__(self):
    if self.options:
        return '<pygments.lexers.%s with %r>' % (self.__class__.__name__,
                                                 self.options)
    else:
        return '<pygments.lexers.%s>' % self.__class__.__name__
```

Sure enough, if I modify it to return only `self.__class__.__name__`, I'll get what I want, but that doesn't feel right.

How can I get what I want? Maybe inheriting the class and then overriding the function or something? Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out the solution was simple. I simply had to use the following:

```
guess_lexer(text).name
```